# Question about why the set of all open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\pi$ system?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I read in a textbook that the set of all open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\pi$ system. The definition of a $\pi$ system is that a collection $A$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is a $\pi$ system if $A \cap B \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$. However, I was unable to reconcile this fact if I let $A = (0,1)$ and $B=(2,3)$. It seems here that $(0,1) \cap (2,3) = \emptyset$. Am I interpreting something wrong?

Comment: You should include the degenerate open interval $(a,a)=\emptyset$.

Comment: so you are saying that $\mathcal{A}$ must include the empty set?

Comment: That's right. But the collection of all open intervals does this, since we can write the empty set as I did.

Comment: Certainly $\emptyset$ is an open set.  It is a degenerate case of an interval, containing no points if $a=b$.